# Improving Dell Desktop wifi range

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dell-inspiron

I bought a new Dell Inspirion 3668 and noticed the wifi signal is very weak. It is only able to handle one tab while browsing at a time and is roughly 20 ft from the router. Is there anything that could improve the wifi range for a desktop?

- What settings work best for expanding the wifi range on a Dell Wireless 1707 802.11 wireless adapter?
- would a new wifi chip or a usb range extension help?
- what router might give a better range?

Comment: Regarding question #3, you want to rule out router problems by connecting with your another device like your phone or tablet, walking about the space.

Comment: I tested it with my phone (an older android) and am able to get wifi in the same location as the dell desktop but it is also a very weak signal. Pages load slowly but can be reached. The further you walk from the router the weaker the signal is and at about 30ft from the router most pages won't load.

Comment: Consumer wireless can generally reach further than that.  Sounds like your wireless router is either having problems or is set to very low power output.  In other words, troubleshooting the Dell won't help.  Log into your wireless router's configuration and see if there's a Power or Transmit Power setting, and set it to normal.  You might choose to Reset All Settings or Set to Factory Default on the wireless router, but that will lose any custom settings that were made before.  You might also test with another wireless router.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I'll have to see if I can try adjusting the router setting to improve the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of things you can do to increase your wireless performance and most of them happen not within the wireless adapter on your Dell machine but from the router firmware itself. There are tons of small technical adjustments you can make and probably the most important thing you can do is to try to upgrade your router's firmware altogether.

If you're not sure how to access your router firmware, try going to a browser and entering 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.0 in the address bar. You'll likely be greeted with a login page and your router manufacturer's branding on it. Typically the default username and password(if unchanged since install) are "admin" and "admin" respectively. You may also try "admin" for the username and leaving the password blank. You can definitely change these to something else once you're logged in. Once in, every router firmware is different but there should be a section to check for an update or upgrade to the firmware.

If you can't get access to the router firmware then your best options are to try switching the band you're using. Most routers released in the past 5 or so years should be dual-band and therefore offer a second network on the 5 Ghz frequency band instead of the conventional 2.4 Ghz band. You could try accessing the former by looking back in the list of available networks. It should look like: "your network name **5**" or "your network name **5G**". Apart from this you may consider using an old or unused second router to act as a wifi extender. You would basically find another router and then connect it to the primary router via an ethernet cable. The second router would ideally be placed closer to your Dell. There's a little more setup involved in this.

[This guide](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2372811,00.asp) gives more detail on some of the measures listed here(including the router extendeder solution). Hope any of these work for you!